# Knockout/Select2: initiating dropdownlist with only placeholder

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-select2

I was wondering if there was a way to initial the dropdownlist with just the placeholder instead of the first value?

**Html**

```
    <select class="select2" data-bind="options: $root.AvailableFrom,
                                                   value: SelectedFrom,
                                                   optionsValue: function(i) {return i.ID},
                                                   optionsText: function(i) {return i.Name},
                                                   select2: {placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', 
                                                  allowClear: false}"></select> </td>
```

**JS**

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element,
        function() {
          $(element).select2('destroy');
        });
      var select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().select2);
      $(element).select2(select2);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
      var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
      if ("value" in allBindings) {
        if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || element.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor != Array) {
          $(element).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
        } else {
          $(element).on('select2:selecting', function (e) {
           // $(this).select2(allBindingsAccessor().options);
              var data = e.params.args.data.id;
              console.log("Selected ID = " + data);
          });
          console.log($(element).select2('data'));
          $(element).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
        }
      }    
      $(element).trigger("change");
    }
  };
```

I've read that if I put `<option></option>` it will default to the placeholder, but since I'm using a `<select>` I'm not quite sure how I would implement that. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the "optionsCaption" section at https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: well.. that worked. I just assumed that I had to use the placeholder from select2